# Pulling from a worktree?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-pull, git-worktree

I have git repository which has a sub module from the same repository but different branch i added it using

```
git worktree add -b develop ../src
```

and when i type: `git worktree list` i get this:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDc4g.png)

but when i try to pull nothing changes in src folder.

i've added in .git/config:

```
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop
```

still nothing changed.

Is there a command that when cloning the repository will pull automatically the sub-module with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I documented in "[What goes wrong when using git worktree with git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872051/6309)", if you are using a Git 2.26+, a [`git checkout --recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---recurse-submodules) ([documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249558/6309)) done inside your new worktree should work with submodules.

Make sure to add your worktree in a patch which is not in the current local cloned repository.

Comment: and if i'm working with 2.25.1 ? do i need to upgrade it ?

Comment: @nessHaf Yes, 2.25 is old: Try 2.30.

Comment: Thank you i've upgraded my git and it worked perfectly