# Does git worktree allow "pulling" from a different worktree?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I am working on the `main` worktree to test my own code for unit tests. I created another work tree (let's call it `integration`) to build a bigger executable as my own code is just a dependency so the 2nd work tree is for something like an integration test.

As I work on my `main` worktree, I discover that I would like to add more logs in the unit tests to figure out what might be wrong. I also think that these logs would be good in the integration tests as well and would like to update my worktree with the most recent changes in `main`.

Is there a way to update the `integration` worktree with something similar to `git pull` from `main`? Something that would look like `git worktree pull`?  If not, is there a workaround as I don't see anything remotely like it in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)?

I don't like the idea of creating a new worktree every time I could have done something like `git worktree pull`.

**NOTE: I don't want to commit changes just yet because nothing is confirmed as working correctly.**

I didn't undestand what this user is trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66042058/pulling-from-a-worktree) and I am not working with submodules.

Comment: A branch is a branch, isn't it? You can always merge one branch into another.  "NOTE: I don't want to commit changes just yet because nothing is confirmed as working correctly." Well then there is no question to answer. In Git, commits are the only thing there is. So you've blocked yourself.

Comment: `worktree`s allow you to copy uncommitted changes to oher places without commits so it is not much to ask to update just the worktree when uncommitted, unstaged changes can be moved around already

Comment: `git worktree pull` makes no sense since all worktrees work on the same repository—there is nothing to pull between worktrees. If you want to copy the unstaged changes from the `main` worktree to your own worktree then you should stop doing what you're doing and just make a branch for `integration` instead.

Comment: "nothing is confirmed working": IMO if something is complete enough for you to desire to use it in an unrelated change, then it's worth commiting. Note that this doesn't mean that you need to push that change to your central repo, or that this individual commit ever needs to exist in the "real history" of the project, but you can just commit as "the log stuff" comment and when stuff **is** ready, you re-arrange stuff into a nice commit (or multiple) before pushing upstream.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, I have never done the re-arranging before. How do you do this? The only way to avoid the issue that I can think of is to `Squash and Merge` the branch change.

Comment: @heretoinfinity: one simple way to do it is to check out the last commit, git reset soft to the last public commit, and then use `git add -p` to pick individual chunks to add (and then commit). This way you can build up a "fictional" history of your changes. Or just commit changes per-file, if that makes sense for your history.  Or just compress it all down to one "do stuff" commit ...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `git diff` and `git apply`

`git diff` creates a "diff file" for your current worktree.
`git apply` applies a diff file to the current worktree

This is the best way to copy uncommitted changes from one worktree to another.

Example:

```
cd /git/main 
git diff > /path/to/difffile
cd /git/integration
git apply /path/to/difffile
```

Note: You can also specify the files you want to include in the diff, if you do not want to copy the changes from all files, only some:

```
git diff -- file1 subdir/file2 > /path/to/difffile
```

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE: I don't want to commit changes just yet because nothing is
> confirmed as working correctly.

That is fine. You can just commit it—commits are not just for working
code.

Commits are like the first-class citizens of Git. Once something is
committed you can do most of what you want to do with what one might
broadly call *changes*:

- Put it on another branch (git-cherry-pick(1))
- Put it and other commits on another branch (git-rebase(1))
- Find when you made the commit with git-reflog(1)
- Toss away the commit and keep the changes (like return it to the staging
  area) with git-reset(1)

But until you commit it they are just changes in your working tree in one
of your worktrees and your options are more limited.

> I don't like the idea of creating a new worktree every time I could have
> done something like git worktree pull.

The goal of using a separate worktree seems to be about getting a
different executable. That makes sense when you are working on something
very different from “main” which might take a while to build. But whether
those changes (relative to `main`) are in a commit or in the staging area
or something else doesn't matter as far as the build is concerned.

So I would use commits and then for example cherry-pick them to wherever
you need them.

#### The purpose of worktrees

[heretoinfinity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7093241/heretoinfinity) asked about the purpose of using worktrees. I surmised
that the goal here was to build different executables. For example, in my
own work I sometimes have to build and deploy something to a server. For
that I might have a worktree called `deploy-dayjob-repo`. The benefit of
that is that I can start the build in that worktree and then work on
something else in another worktree; I won't have to worry about
interfering with the build by making changes or changing branches, since
my worktree doesn't interfere with the `deploy-dayjob-repo` worktree. But
keep in mind that this extra step is optional. If, say, the build and
deploy only took a little while I might have not used a separate worktree
for that. Or I might have waited for it to complete and gotten a cup of
coffee/tea.

On the purpose and uses of worktrees in general I have written about it
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76026941/1725151). See also the other answers on that question.

Comment: Could you clarify what the goal(s) of a separate worktree is/are if not for just a different executable?

Comment: @heretoinfinity I've added a section on that now :)